# Getting a value in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My lack of Javascript skills are really showing here, but I am having a problem.

I have built a chart using Highcharts.js and I am trying to customize the tooltip display. It is a range chart and by default point.y returns the low value. I have no idea how to return the high value.

Can anyone help? Here is the formatter code and I have also created a jsfiddle.

```
       formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {

                s += '<br/>Maximum Value: ?<br/>Minimum Value: ' + point.y 
                + '<br/>Spread Value: Max-Min';
            });

            return s;
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cCrLh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of objects from points array contain `point` property which is true object from Highcharts. Then you have access to `point.high` and `point.low`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cCrLh/3/

```
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<br/>Maximum Value: ' + point.point.high + '<br/>Minimum Value: ' + point.point.low
                + '<br/>Spread Value: Max-Min';
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Can you point me to a resource where I would see this documented? Or would I have just figured it out with better skills?

Comment: @drummin, I recommend doing something like `console.log(point)` inside the `$.each` block in your code. this will write the object to your browser console. It is packed with info! Also the highcharts API docs are very good (although not clear that these point high/low values are accessible).

Comment: You know, I tried that and it didn't work. I figured it had something to do with being in a fiddle.

Comment: The problem was that you have overwritten console.log to get info inside HTML, it won't work that way. Anyway, wergeld has right, it's hard to write docs and list all of options (and keep them updated), there is only small info in docs about `this.points[i].point` like .name ( [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) )